# Joda-Time DateTimeZone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I have a unit test which attempts to verify some behavior between Israel/London, one of the first things I check is the timezone offset in `Asia/Jerusalem` as follows

```
val clientTimezone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jerusalem")
val now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT"))
val clientOffset = clientTimezone.getOffset(now) / (1000 * 60)
```

Right now it's 5pm in London, 7pm in Israel, and 4pm GMT, but when I run this code I get `now` initialized to 16:00, and `clientOffset` = 120 not 180.  If I swap `Asia/Jerusalem` for `Europe/London` I get a `clientOffset` = 60.

Am I using Joda correctly, or does it have the wrong time?  These tests were fine before this weekend.  This is with version joda-time 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time zone rules for Israel have changed.  You'll need to use the 2013d version of the IANA time zone database.  This is included in JodaTime 2.3.

If you can't update JodaTime, you can update the TZDB data separately following [these instructions](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html).